# Manual integration in Sympy doesn't work correctly with noncommutative symbols

Tags: python, sympy

I have the following

```
x=Symbol('x',commutative=False)
y=Symbol('y',commutative=False)
expr = 2*x + 87*x*y + 7*y
```

Now, this works

```
integrate(expr,y,manual=True)
```

because it gives

```
2*x*y + 87*x*y**2/2 + 7*y**2/2
```

but the same exact thing with x fails:

```
integrate(expr,x,manual=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy/integrals/integrals.py", line 1295, in integrate
    risch=risch, manual=manual)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy/integrals/integrals.py", line 486, in doit
    conds=conds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy/integrals/integrals.py", line 774, in _eval_integral
    poly = f.as_poly(x)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy/core/basic.py", line 706, in as_poly
    poly = Poly(self, *gens, **args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy/polys/polytools.py", line 113, in __new__
    opt = options.build_options(gens, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy/polys/polyoptions.py", line 731, in build_options
    return Options(gens, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy/polys/polyoptions.py", line 154, in __init__
    preprocess_options(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy/polys/polyoptions.py", line 152, in preprocess_options
    self[option] = cls.preprocess(value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy/polys/polyoptions.py", line 293, in preprocess
    raise GeneratorsError("non-commutative generators: %s" % str(gens))
sympy.polys.polyerrors.GeneratorsError: non-commutative generators: (x,)
```

Why Sympy is so weird? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem satisfied with

```
integrate(2*x + 87*x*y + 7*y, y, manual=True)
```

returning

```
2*x*y + 87*x*y**2/2 + 7*y**2/2
```

But the first term of this answer could also be `2*y*x`. Or `x*y + y*x`. And these are all different answers. So, is the notion of an integral with noncommutative symbols well-defined to begin with? Maybe it's not that SymPy is weird, but the question you are asking it is.

---

The concrete reason for this behavior is that manual integration is based on matching certain patterns. Such as "constant times something" pattern:

```
coeff, f = integrand.as_independent(symbol)
```

The method `as_independent`  splits the product as `independent * possibly_dependent`, in this order. So,

```
(x*y).as_independent(y)  # returns (x, y)
(x*y).as_independent(x)  # returns (1, x*y)
```

As a result, constant factors are recognized only in front of the expression, when the product is noncommutative.

I don't think this can be fixed without rewriting one of the core methods `as_independent` to support noncommutative products (possibly returning `independent * dependent * independent2`) which looks like a lot of work to me. Before doing that work, I'd want to know whether the objective (antiderivative with noncommuting variables) is well defined.